# changing part of the URL string in base to click events of two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to change a part of a URL string in base to clicks in two different buttons.
If I click the first one the value of a key in the URL string will be one. If I click the second button that value in the URL string will be different.

This URL is the first parameter of .getJSON method.

I tried different ways with jQuery, for example:

```
var myString= "one string";
var myUrl="http://theweb.com?"+myString;
$("button_one").click(function(){
           myString="one string";
});
$("button_two").click(function(){
           myString="other string";
});

$.getJSON(myUrl,function(json){...})
```

but no result.Clicking the second button don't change the string in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code $.getJSON is called even before you actually click any button.
try using the getJson inside the events.

```
var myString= "one string";
var myUrl="http://theweb.com?"+myString;
$("button_one").click(function(){
           myString="one string";
           $.getJSON(myUrl,function(json){...})
});
$("button_two").click(function(){
           myString="other string";
           $.getJSON(myUrl,function(json){...})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to reassign the value to `myUrl` and properly recall the `$.getJSON` for this it's usually best making a function (`doRequest`):

```
$("button_one").click(function() {
  doRequest("one string");
});
$("button_two").click(function(){
  doRequest("other string");
});

// Do initial request, are you sure you want this?
doRequest("one string");

function doRequest(myString) {
  var myUrl="http://theweb.com?" + myString;
  $.getJSON(myUrl,function(json) {
    // ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update "myUrl" before you use it in your getJSON call. You haven't actually changed anything. Also, should probably use a local variable in each function.

```
$("button_one").click(function(){
           var myUrl="http://theweb.com?" + "one string";
           $.getJSON(myUrl,function(json){...})
});
$("button_two").click(function(){
           var myUrl="http://theweb.com?" + "other string";
           $.getJSON(myUrl,function(json){...})
});
```

Comment: Yes, we need to define the URL in each of the click events.

Comment: Edited to use a local variable in each function. In this example you can know exactly what the url is, then call getJSON with it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here. You need to assign it to the variable after you have set the myString.
Also you don't have the . in the button_one and button_two
which would be for the class.
for a class you need .button_one
or for an id you need #button_one

```
<button class="button_one" href="#">Button One</button>
    <button class="button_two" href="#">Button Two</button>



<script>

    $(window).load(function () {
        var myString= "one string";

        $(".button_one").click(function(){
            myString="one string";
            var myUrl="http://theweb.com?"+myString;
            console.log(myUrl);
        });
        $(".button_two").click(function(){
            myString="other string";
            var myUrl="http://theweb.com?"+myString;
            console.log(myUrl);
        });

      //  $.getJSON(myUrl,function(json){})
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces in your urls.
If you are using ids to select your buttons, prefix them with `#` ex: `$("#button_two")`. 
To change the href of a url you can use `$(selector).prop('href',value);`
In your button clicks, you are updating myString, but you never reevaluate myUrl.

Here is a working example:

```js
var myUrl = "http://theweb.com?";

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#button_one").click(function() {
    $("a#myUrl").prop('href', myUrl + "one_string");
    $('span').text($("a#myUrl").attr('href'));
  });
  
  $("#button_two").click(function() {
    $("a#myUrl").prop('href', myUrl + "two_string");
    $('span').text($("a#myUrl").attr('href'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a id="myUrl" href="">My URL</a>
<br />
<span>URL: </span>
<br />
<button id="button_one">Button One</button>
<br />
<button id="button_two">Button Two</button>
```